# deployed apache + django application access local files outside project directory

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to develop a django web app to be used locally where I work. the problem is there are some reports that I am transforming to be HTML based. some of the data being used in my app exist in excel files that are located on a network drive.

In development I can access all the files without any problem with there absolute path. example: 'Z:/dataFile.xls'. when deploying my app on an apache server + mod_wsgi I keep getting an error that the file is not found. I have checked multiple answers and all of them seems to be concentrated on the static files within the project directory itself.

my setup is:

- windows 7 (64 bit)
- python 3.5 (64)
- Django 1.8
- apache 2.4.20-win64-VC14
- mod_wsgi-4.4.23+ap24vc14

the app is deployed without any problems when I move the files within the application's static files folder I am able to read them with no problem. the problem is only when I try to read from an external location (i.e. network drive or simply from C drive but giving the absolute path to the file as I have mentioned)

these files need to be read from these locations, because the users edit them and these values are included in this report.

If anyone have a better solution to enable the user to edit the files and at the same time the application can read them.

thanks.

Comment: Apache by default can't access files outside of its limited ecosystem. If you want it to access filesystem contents you need to configure it to do so. See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/325498/apache-cant-access-folders-in-my-home-directory

Comment: Is the Apache server in the same machine as your dev server? If yes, are you using any virtual machine or docker or anything that may "sandbox" your server and prevent access to the file system?

Comment: currently yes my apache server is on the same machine as my dev server. This is my first time developing a django application and I was in the testing phase on how to deploy it to production. there are no virtual machines used. even django is not used as a virtualenv. they all exists on the same physical machine.

Comment: the directory option given by Ivan, works fine when it is a local directory on the machine. does not work if the specified location is on a network mapped drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after trying the solution provided in the comment of Ivan [allow Apache to access folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325498/apache-cant-access-folders-in-my-home-directory). I have tested it on local folders and it worked fine. when trying it with network drives (eg: "Z:\shared_folder") apache couldn't recognize them. I have tried then to write the actual path the shared folder (eg: "\server_name\shared_folder") and it worked just fine. Just note if you are running apache as a service you need to change the username that the service uses. first you need to edit the username access rights and add [Log on as a service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc784323(v=ws.10).aspx) & [Act as part of the operating system](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc739424(v=ws.10).aspx) then open the services "Services.msc", open the apache service, then under the log on tab change the username from local system account. this will make sure that the service has access to the shared folder on the network drive